# xticks values as dataframe column values in matplotlib plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I have data.frame below

```
      values    years
0    24578.0  2007-09
1    37491.0  2008-09
2    42905.0  2009-09
3    65225.0  2010-09
4   108249.0  2011-09
5   156508.0  2012-09
6   170910.0  2013-09
7   182795.0  2014-09
8   233715.0  2015-09
9   215639.0  2016-09
10  215639.0      TTM
```

The plotted image is attached, the issue is i want years values '2007-09' to 'TTM' as `xtick` values in plot

[image: The plotted image is ataached,the issue is i want years values '2007-09' to 'TTM' as xtick values in plot]

Answer (score 8):

One way to do this would be to access the current idices of the xticks in the x data. Use that value to select the values from `df.year` and then set the labels to those values:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(ax=ax)
tick_idx = plt.xticks()[0]
year_labels = df.years[tick_idx].values
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(year_labels)
```

[image]

You could also set the x axis to display all years like so:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(ax=ax, xticks=df.index, rot=45)
ax.set_xticklabels(df.years)
```

[image]